# Is there a way to display more than 7 strips/channels in video sequencer?

Tags: interface, video-sequence-editor

By default blender video sequencer will show only 7 strips in the viewport. There can be more strips in the project, but you have to scroll up to see them and work with them. For usability purposes I'd like to have more strips visible (say 14). But cannot find this option in the preferences and on the internet. Maybe still it can be done somehow? Maybe there is a constant in config file or source files that can be changed from 7 to 14 for this particular purpose.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: you can either make the window bigger or in the window scale the y scale as you would do in viewport (zoom in and out)

Comment: There is an option, I just don’t remember how. It involves holding a key and scrolling as I remember.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried making window bigger, but no effect. It will simply "stretch" strips.
CTRL+ (Mouse Wheel pressed drag down) did the trick. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can scale the y scale as you would do in viewport (zoom in and out) using ctrl + middle-mouse-button

[image]

The view will often seem limited 'to 7 or 8 channels if 'View' > 'Limit view to contents' is checked. Once deselected, you should be able see as many channels as you like.

[image]